# Japplet Error: noclassdeffounderror com/esri/map/layer

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, arcgis, japplet

So I've been trying to get a japplet that uses arcgis sdk jar files to run in a browser and I can't seem to get past this error (noclassdeffounderror com/esri/map/layer).
I think this means that I am not exporting my main.jar file with the external arcgis jars but I am not sure as I have tried a few different ways to get the external jars anyways.
I have tried referencing them in the html file like so: (with the arcgis lib copied to the folder with Main.jar in it)

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <center>
         <applet
             archive = "Main.jar",
             lib.ArcGIS_Runtime_Java.jar,
             lib.ArcGIS_Runtime_Java_Toolkit.jar
             code = "General.Main"
         >
     </center>
  </body>
```

I have also tried exporting the jar with the dependencies added however to do this in eclipse it seems that you much have a main(String args[]) method which JApplets cannot have.
I have marked the libs and jars needed in buildpath - order and exports.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Start by trying to [validate the HTML](https://validator.w3.org/).

E.G. this..

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <center>
         <applet
             archive = "Main.jar",
             lib.ArcGIS_Runtime_Java.jar,
             lib.ArcGIS_Runtime_Java_Toolkit.jar
             code = "General.Main"
         >
     </center>
  </body>
```

Should be more like this:

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <center>
         <applet
             archive = "Main.jar, lib.ArcGIS_Runtime_Java.jar, lib.ArcGIS_Runtime_Java_Toolkit.jar"
             code = "General.Main"
             width = "400"
             height = "300"
         >
         </applet>
     </center>
  </body>
```